# How can I select a bootstrap checkbox in an e2e test using Nightwatch?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I have a bootstrap checkbox that looks something like this:`<b-checkbox id="boxID" v-model="doThings">I understand... </b-checkbox>`

Now, I'm writing e2e tests using nightwatch, and I can't get that checkbox selected.

I tried to do `this.setValue("@boxID", true)` this brings focus to the checkbox but does not select it. 
Tried to do `this.click("@boxID")` but that does nothing at all.
I tried to bring focus then click, and that did not work either...

Is there a clean way to get checkboxes checked with Nightwatch?

I found this [article](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/249) on the repository of Nightwatch but it offered workarounds, not direct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way

```
.verify.visible('input[id="boxID"]', 'Checkbox visible')
      .click('input[id="boxID"]')
```

Comment: @j0zeft is this solved your issue if not let me know.

Comment: it did not, but I set focus to it, then send " " which is basically pressing the space bar to select it.

Comment: then send keystroke to it `browser.Keys.SPACE`